# 自作したソフトウェアを apt 経由でインストールできるよう配布したい

Tags: ubuntu, apt

自作のソフトウェアをaptコマンドで他のユーザにインストールして貰えるような格好にしたいのですが方法がわからず困っています。
どなたかよろしければアドバイスをお願いします。

自分の環境では `/etc/apt/sours.list` にデフォルトで

```
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

の記述がありますので、恐らくはこのリポジトリからaptコマンドを利用して、皆さんの作成されたソフトウェアを自分の環境に複製してくる設定になっているかと思うのですが、この度質問させていただきたいのは、この http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/  から、私の作成したソフトを他者が複製できるようにすることは可能であるかどうかという事と。

もしも可能である場合、どのような手順で可能になるかをお伺いできればと思い投稿させていただきました。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 皆様回答ありがとうございました。 実現可能性がありそうなものから、試してみたいと思います。 同じ質問で、
ubuntuの日本語フォーラムのほうでは以下の回答をいただきました。
https://forums.ubuntulinux.jp/viewtopic.php?id=20164
ご興味ある方は参考までにどうぞ。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`の実体は、`ubuntutym.u-toyama.ac.jp/ubuntu/`で、富山大学からサーバーの提供を受けて、Ubuntu Japanese Team がメンテナンスをおこなっている Ubuntuのパッケージアーカイブミラーです。Ubutuの公式パッケージの配布のためのサイトなので、自作のソフトウェアの配布に使用するのは難しいと思われます。
・Ubuntu Japanese Team [日本国内のダウンロードサイト](https://www.ubuntulinux.jp/ubuntu/mirrors)

Ubuntuには、非公式リポジトリ [Personal Package Archives for Ubuntu (略称でPPA）](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) があります。自作のソフトウェアの配布する場合は、それを利用すればいいと思いす。PPAに登録すると、`add-apt-repository`コマンドで、そのリポジトリをマシンに登録できるので、自作のソフトウェアの利用者が`apt`コマンドでインストールや更新を簡単にできるようになります。特に、アップデートがあるかどうか自動でチェックできるというのが便利だと思います。

PPAの利用については、[PPAの help page](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) をみてください。

Answer (score 9):

> http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com

は、Canonical社がメンテナンスしているリポジトリですので、自作パッケージを登録するのは困難かと思われます。

> 自作のソフトウェアをaptコマンドで他のユーザにインストールして貰えるような格好にしたい

という目的でしたら、APTパッケージを作成し、自分でリポジトリを立て、そこで配布するというのが簡単かと存じます。
（ちなみに、aptコマンドではなくdpkgコマンドを使ってもらうようにすれば、リポジトリを立てる手間が省けて直接GitHubやファイルサーバから配布が可能になるためより簡単かと思います。）

参考：

[第 15 章 Debian パッケージの作成](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/ja-JP/stable/debian-packaging.html)

[15.3. APT 用のパッケージリポジトリの作成](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/ja-JP/stable/sect.setup-apt-package-repository.html)

Comment: 最近の `apt` コマンドは `apt install ./ほにゃらら.deb` という感じに `*.deb` ファイルを直接インストールできます。参考: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159114/211480

Comment: 知りませんでした、最近は `apt` だけで解決できるんですね